# IONIC 2 : Push notifications icon white square

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic2, icons

When my Android phone (Andoid 8.0) receives a push notification from my app, the icon is blank/white. It works when I use `$ ionic cordova resources --icon` with an icon with transparent background, but when I do that my app icon has no background, and I don't want that.

It's possible to use differents icons for app and for notification ? I tried a lot of things but nothing works.

I'm using Ionic 2 push plugin to show push notification, I used this post to do my code : https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-version-2/push-notification-in-ionic-2-native-plugin-version-2-3-with-firebase-hosting-service-provider

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a different icon for your notifications. Just specify an icon in your PushOptions when you initialize the push plugin. If you dont specify an icon it uses the app icon by default.

```
const options: PushOptions = {
   android: {
       icon: your_drawable_icon
   }
};

const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
```

Read more about available (android) options in the [Ionic Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/#AndroidPushOptions) and for more details directly in the [phonegap-push-plugin repo](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#images)

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't works, I add the icon but it doesn't works

Comment: Hmm seems to be a plugin specific issue. Maybe look into this issue https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1924. How do you send your messages?

Comment: I send message via Firebase Notification console.

Comment: I tride to send notification via PHP and the notifications icon is perfect, it seems that it only not working with Firebase console.

Comment: Good to hear that! Thats exactly what happened to the guy in the issue.

Comment: @SébastienHabsiger can you please provide the payload you are using to send notifications? Than you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add icon manually in your platform project (Android Native method)

1. create ic_notification.png
2. find directory  `\platforms\android\res\`
3. In res directory you can see many `drawable` or `mipmap` directory, Copy ic_notification in all these directories.
4. Open `AndroidManifest.xml` located in `\platforms\android\`
5. Inside `<application > ... </application >` tag add following config

   if drawable

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
   ```

   if mipmap

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
   ```

***Note this setting may overwritten if you clean and rebuild your project. or if you run platform remove/update/add command